# How can i load data and display it using CouchBase Lite

Tags: android, document, couchbase-lite

I'm a in the process of understanding  CouchBase Lite for android application,as far i only know how to create a manager, database, document and view.However i want to load data from the documents and show it int the app but failed after trying several times and following some tutorials.Is there a way i can load this data and manipulate it?
The code i used til now is the following:

```
        // create a manager
        Manager manager;
        try {
            manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(this), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            getFilesDir();
            return;
        }
        // create a name for the database and make sure the name is legal
        String app4 = "list";
        if (!Manager.isValidDatabaseName(app4)) {
            return;
        }
// create a new database

        Database database;
        try {
            database = manager.getDatabase(app4);
            Log.d (TAG, "Database created");


        } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot get database");
            return;
        }

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("title", " Au bonheur des dames");
        properties.put("author", "Emile ZOla");

//        Document document = database.createDocument();
//        Document retrievedDocument = database.getDocument(documentID);
        Document document = database.createDocument();

        try {
            document.putProperties(properties);
        } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot save document", e);
        }

        Query query = database.createAllDocumentsQuery();

        try {
            QueryEnumerator queryEnumerator = query.run();
            List<QueryRow> results = new ArrayList<QueryRow>();

            for (int i=0; i< queryEnumerator.getCount(); i++) {
                results.add(queryEnumerator.getRow(i));
            }
```

If anyone could help please, i would be very thankful.As i said i am very new to Couchbase and thus may commit a lot of mistakes...

Comment: Does your document wind up in the results List?  Where is the code that tries to display results?

Comment: Thank you elevine for ur answer,well that's exactly my problem,i dont know how to deal with it so i can display and extract the data,I tried to retriev the docuent ... but didnt work for me

Comment: Go through documentation properly http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an in-depth look into map/reduce techniques to create an '[View](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html),' which is an index of documents in the database and from there '[Query](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html)' to look up the result of the index that the View provides.

Going over the Couchbase Mobile [mini-hack tutorial](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mini-hacks/tree/master/kitchen-sync/android) and specifically focus on steps 3-5 and 8 would help with further understanding on how to load and display data.